# Float to varchar with style 3 is failing in sql server 2016

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014, sql-server-2016

I am getting Arithmetic overflow error while executing following query on sql server 2016.

```
"select convert(varchar(20), cast('0' as float), 3)"
```

The same query works fine on sql server 2014.

[image]

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Looks like XY problem. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are getting this error cause `casting '0' to float of style 3  returning 23 charter value which is unable to convert to varchar of length 20 only`.

try something like,

```
select convert(varchar(23), cast('0' as float), 3)
```

Or

```
select convert(varchar(max), cast('0' as float), 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

CONVERT ( data_type [ ( length ) ] , expression **[ , style ]** )

> The same query works fine 
>   on sql server 2014.

style in sql 2014

> Other values are processed as 0.
>   A maximum of 6 digits. Use in scientific notation, when appropriate.

style in sql 2016

> **3** Always 17 digits. Use for lossless conversion. With this style, every distinct float or real value is guaranteed to convert to a
>   distinct character string.Applies to: Azure SQL Database, and **starting in SQL Server 2016.**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql